# Collective noun for lightning(s) / thunderbolts

Tags: terminology, collective-nouns, literary-english

What is the collective noun for lightning(s) / thunderbolts?

> A ________ of thunderbolts/lightning(s)

Can we use the plural form of lightning with a collective noun? Or should it stay in singular form?

For example:

> The valleys of Grand Canyon were being struck by a ________ of lightnings and rumbling like a giant open-air opera house with the following thunders.

(Note: This would be a literary sentence than an everyday speech)

[image: Grand Canyon with lots of lightning on other side]

**Note:** A single lightning event is mentioned as a *flash* and if it hits the ground or an object, it is mentioned as a *strike.*

**Note 2:** Lightning is generally a mass noun but it can be used as a count noun also, especially in literary sense. [OED](http://books.google.ca/books?id=anecAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA1022&dq=oxford%20dictionary%20lightning#v=onepage&q=oxford%20dictionary%20lightning&f=false) has a definition for the literary sense as a count noun:

> ***[count noun] literary*** a flash or discharge of lightning: *the sky was a mass of black cloud out of which lightnings were flashed.*

You can find literary usages in Google Books as well. Plural form was more common in 1800s and the usage has dropped dramatically but there are still some contemporary usages.

[image]

Lightning is used in plural form in technical contexts also. Below are the examples from a technical book called "[Lightning Physics and Lightning Protection](http://books.google.ca/books?id=Cr6KrKUJLesC&pg=PA119&dq=%22of%20lightnings%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=JorIU9W2BJSsyASU8IF4&ved=0CEcQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=%22lightnings%22&f=false)" (by By Eduard M. Bazelyan, Yuri P. Raizer) also.

> The statistics of flight accidents show that aircraft of identical size may differ considerably  in the capacity to excite lightnings.
>
> ---
>
> The lightnings people observe most frequently are descending discharges, which originate among storm clouds and strike the earth or objects located on its surface.

Thunderbolt is a count noun.

**Note 3:** Below is a similar question asked before: 
[Collective Noun for Fire](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/81023/collective-noun-for-fire?rq=1)

The difference between fire and lightning in the context of countability is that fire is also both countable and uncountable but both senses have a common usage.

Comment: _Lightning_ is a mass noun. Mass nouns don't have collectives; that's only count nouns. Since it's a mass noun, to speak of one event, one has to use a classifier like _a stroke of lightning_ or _a bolt of lightning_, or as in the picture, _a lightning event_.

Comment: *Very, very frightening*? Perhaps a *Galileo* of thunder and lightening?

Comment: You can’t have **lightnings* to start with.

Comment: I'd like to see an example in context of *lightening* being used as a singular or countable noun *in a literary sense*. I don't follow you on that. Also, *lightnings* (plural) is never users, as far as I know.

Comment: @Jim: [OED](http://books.google.ca/books?id=anecAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA1022&dq=oxford+dictionary+lightning) has a definition if you want a proof and you can check usages in Google Books.

Comment: The standard collocation is [**thunder and lightning**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=thunder+and+lightning%2Clightning+and+thunder%2Cthunderbolts+and+lightning%2Clightning+and+thunderbolts&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthunder%20and%20lightning%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clightning%20and%20thunder%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthunderbolts%20and%20lightning%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clightning%20and%20thunderbolts%3B%2Cc0). *Thunderbolts* is relatively uncommon/poetic, and neither *thunder* nor *lightning* are usually pluralised...

Comment: ...and the standard word to fill in OP's blank is a [***barrage** of thunder and lightning*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22barrage+of+thunder+and+lightning%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl). But I think the question here seems miscontrued/subjective.

Comment: The "please fill in this blank" part of the question is still "primarily opinion based". And all the misleading stuff about plural *lightnings* is still there. And *barrage* isn't a "collective noun" for elements of electrical storms. I've closevoted because I can't see anything here except an Off Topic "writing advice" request. (My advice is *"Stop trying to defend plural **lightnings** - it's not normal English"* :)

Comment: Your own evidence suggests only that pluralising it is ok in "literary" or "technical" English. To refer to an individual lightning event native speakers would refer to "lightning bolts",  "lightning strikes", perhaps "flashes of lightning". Things like "lightning" and "a lightning" sound odd.

Comment: @ermanen: What I mean by "normal" English is what people normally say - as illustrated by the fact that Google Books claims almost 2000 instances of [*scared of **lightning***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22scared+of+lightning%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl), but not a single one for the plural [*scared of **lightnings***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22scared+of+lightnings%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl). There are a couple of plural *scared of thunderbolts*, but none for ***thunders*** (and that's against 3670 instances of *scared of **thunder***).

Comment: @ermanen I'm sorry if I wasn't clear, I was responding to your questioning FumbleFingers' reference to "normal" English and just trying to point out that to me it made sense as a contrast to the types of English you were talking about. However many examples you find, I am certain that in conversation, native speakers would hear "lightnings" as a *mistake*. To me, this seems like useful information.

Comment: @JohnLawler In what way is a collective noun (in the sense of “a _murder_ of crows”, etc.) anything more than just another type of classifier like “a _flash_ of lightning”? Whether an open office window causes a _flurry of papers in the air_ or a _flurry of paper in the air_ seems quite irrelevant to me in this context: the flurry is a collective noun in both cases.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I don't think we disagree, though venereal terms like _murder of crows_ are pretty archaic.

Comment: _blaze of lightnings_ appears in number of books. Hard to tell if it's being used as collective noun. I also found _gambols of lightnings_ which seems even more like a collective noun candidate.

Comment: Did you find a collective noun for _thunders_ ?

Comment: Why am I tempted to say a *battery of lightening*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Lightning* is the generic term for this weather phenomenon. In normal, non-technical English an individual instance is a *lightning flash*, a *bolt of lightning* or a *lightning strike*. There is no collective noun for them.

However, you could refer to a set of lightning flashes, bolts or strikes by one of the nouns used to describe a group of objects or phenomena. I would suggest something like a *succession of lightning flashes*. Besides *electrical storm*, the term *lightning storm* also exists as a way of implying or describing multiple lightning flashes.

Other suggestions in a non-exhaustive list of possibilities: *barrage, volley, parade, procession, sequence* and *display,* depending on which aspect or characteristic of the irruption of flashes seems most salient for the context in which you are describing them.

Because discharges of lightning are ephemeral, and do all not occur simultaneously even during a violent electrical storm, they do not exist as **groups** in the same sense as a group of children exists, say -- which would be one reason for the lack of a collective noun.

Answer (score 3):

You can call it a *cascade* of thunderbolts/lightning.

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cascade) defines the noun form of *cascade* as:

> a large amount of something that flows or hangs down
>
> a large number of things that happen quickly in a series

You can also use *cascade* as a verb.  Merriam-Webster defines the verb form of *cascade* as:

> to fall, pour, or rush in or as if in a cascade

An example using cascade as a verb: Lightning cascaded across the sky over the valleys of the Grand Canyon.

Also, [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lightnings#English) says that *lightnings* as a plural form of lightning is archaic.

Comment: So, Are you sure that we cannot use "a cascade of lightnings"? (lightning in plural form)

Comment: Sure you can use it, it has been used before: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22cascade+of+lightnings%22

But it is an archaic usage.

Comment: There are also contemporary usages of the plural form of lightning in literature. Can we say that "collective noun + plural form of lightning" is an archaic usage then? Or maybe there are other collective nouns used today. I'm not sure.

Comment: *Lightning* is the generic term for this weather phenomenon. In normal, non-technical English an individual instance is a *lightning flash, a bolt of lightning* or a *lightning strike*. There is no collective noun for them. However, you could refer to a set of lightning flashes, bolts or strikes by one of the nouns used to describe a group of objects or phenomena. I would suggest something like *a succession of lightning flashes*. (Because they are ephemeral, they do not exist as **groups** in the same sense as a group of children exists, say -- one reason for the lack of a collective noun.)

Comment: Other suggestions in a non-exhaustive list of possibilities: *barrage, parade, procession, sequence, display*, depending on which characteristic of the irruption of flashes seems most salient for the context in which you are describing them.

Comment: @ErikKowal: Thanks for the explanation, this could be a good answer. Hopefully if this question is re-opened, it would be nice if you can include an answer also. Other than that, what is your opinion in technical and literary context?

Comment: @ermanen - Weather.com did not expand on the usual understanding or usage of the term: see the entries [here](http://www.weather.com/glossary/l.html) and [here](http://www.weather.com/encyclopedia/thunder/light.html). I have nothing useful to say about the phenomenon of lightning in literature.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this on the web, from the [facebook page of Herald and New - Klamath Falls, Ore.](https://www.facebook.com/HandN/posts/10151829496701474).

> A *barrage of lightning* overnight touched off about 60 small fires in southwest and south-central Oregon, and more are expected to become apparent today.

And another, from the [National Park Traveller web site](http://www.nationalparkstraveler.com/2011/08/barrage-lightning-strikes-spawns-six-fires-across-yellowstone-national-park8686)

> *Barrage Of Lightning* Strikes Spawns Six Fires Across Yellowstone National Park

Comment: So? There are virtually infinitely many possible formulations like that. That is not a collective noun dedicated to *lightning*.

Comment: That does not make it any less effective or inappropriate to describe a collection of lightnings.

Comment: Then this is a list question that should be closed as Too Broad because it is just a guessing game or beauty pageant **which can have no single right answer**.

Comment: If we cannot find any other word that is used as often as barrage to describe a collection of lightnings, then that is the best answer.

Comment: Neither of these is a *barrage of lightnings*. One is a mass noun (lightning); the other an attributive noun (lightning strikes). If anything, this answer supports the view that *lightning* cannot be countable.

Comment: I don't know that I would call it "the right answer". The use of barrage in the listed examples doesn't in anyway allude to the fact that thunder and lightning are being described; it only describes the onslaught of the lightning. As @tchrist says there is no single right answer. If I were describing destruction wrought by lightning I might use barrage, but were I to discuss the auditory qualities of a storm I might refer to the thunder as a cacophony.

Comment: Also, please provide at least a minimal textual citation for your quotes following SE's [recently promulgated policy](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Reasons behind the policy appear in [a Meta post](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4981/18696).